# Run a R script on demand from Slack or from a website

Tags: r, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I have an R script that uses a .csv file as an input, and creates another .csv file as an output. Nowadays the user has to email me the .csv file, then I manually run the script and email him the output back. This is very inconvenient

Can a Slack bot automate this task? The user sends the .csv to the bot, and the bot sends the output back

If Slack is not an option, do you know of any web page that allows the user to upload the file, and then download the output? The most important thing is that it is free and easy to set up

Comment: You could turn the script into a [Shiny app](https://shiny.rstudio.com/) and host it on [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/).

Comment: Creating a `plumber`-based HTTP API would work. What resources do you have available? R is not a readily-available language on most servers, it needs to be rather explicit (often with Connect, Shiny Server, or some other R-friendly service).

Comment: Plumbr (and its higher-performance cousin [RestRserve](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RestRserve)) can do this for you. But in essence you are asking for a free hosting service for 'any R code' and sadly those do not exist -- so you are now in the realm of a) likely having to rent a (virtual, partial) server and b) learn enough system administration to keep it afloat.  So maybe the email option isn't so bad in light of that.